# What is that? How can I make it disapear?

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

What is that red line above the cursor? 
How can I turn it off?
What did I press?
questions over questions about a red line in the 3d Viewport

thanks for helping!

Comment: Does it still appear if you move the view port/camera? Can you right click it? Is this in Orthographic mode? Can you find anything unexpected in the Outliner. What add-ons do you have enabled. Can you post the file for review? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruAQ7GZS4gQ here a screen capture of the object. It now lost its white thingies on the left a t right side